# I want to connect two or more ListViews

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I have a ListView, say l1 in a Linear Layout in my xml. Dynamically Im adding another ListView, say l2 to the LinearLayout. Its working fine, but when I run it on my mobile, each list (ie., l1 or l2) are floating on the screen.

My approach to solve this problem.
1. I wanted to fix both the ListViews to the layout. So, that they dont move and it will seem continuous. So I tried to remove scrollable action, thinking it would solve my problem. But couldnt do it, dint get good clue.

1. Next, I thought i will connect those ListViews by adding l2 as a footer to l1. Here also I faced a problem. When added l2 as a footer to l1, only the header of l2 was added as a footer to l1. The l2 body was missing.

How yo solve this issue.
I have spent more than three days in working with this. But, couldnt get a solution.
Please help me out.

Thanks 
Vaishnavi

Comment: pretty sure you just need 1 list view. just add more data objects to the list which supplies the listview's adapter

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, and correct me if I am wrong, you want to new data to your ListView? In order to create two views such that they are seamless, it would imagine that the lists contain the same sort of data.

So, if I understand you correctly, you should simply modify the ListView adapter's underlying data structure to support the new list items that you want. You could define a method in the adapter that will add data, or perhaps create a new adapter with the new data set that contains both items. This should fix your problem.